# Video Rendering at 2x Speed

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

The video rendered at a normal speed before seen here (it just is missing audio in the first half):

Now that I got the audio working in the first half ([AE - Composition video file/layer missing audio](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/ae-composition-video-file-layer-missing-audio/15344?noredirect=1#comment20861_15344)) it's rendering at 2x speed. Not sure if this is happening after the After Effects render or at the Adobe Media Encoder render (can't tell because I render the After Effect render at best quality and it's too slow to playback on any local video player software, Windows Media Player, VLC, ect.., so I can't determine if this is when it first gets rendered at 2x speed).

I saw this question here on StackExchange ([How to force After Effects to interpret footage at a specific framerate?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/6987/how-to-force-after-effects-to-interpret-footage-at-a-specific-framerate)), but I checked the local raw video file's properties for their framerate and it says 29, same as it being rendered in both places. I render from Adobe AfterEffects with "best & lossless" quality settings and then from Adobe Media Encoder with H.264 YouTube 1080p HD, both say rendering at 29 framerate.

Here's what my "composition Settings" looks like:
[image]

and render settings:
[image]

Thanks for any input. :)

Comment: Please check your composition settings: _Composition > Settings_. Also for preview purposes you could encode your composition with after effects to `.mov` with `h264` or in older versions to  `.mp4` directly.

Comment: Hey @poor, composition settings have the right framerate. I took screen shots of my composition settings and render settings windows.

Comment: It makes sense to render a preview or just a part of it as I suggested, to determine if the issue is caused by after effects or media encoder. Did you tried to encode it with ae?

Comment: @poor, I saw no output version for `H.264` in any of the After Effects render options. Do I just choose `.mp4` directly? Also, are you saying to do a RAM Preview?

Comment: I think the last version with _h264 support_ is CS5 - but as i mentioned: you could encode it as _Quicktime and h.264_ in newer versions for a preview.

Comment: Footage Settings? http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/6987/how-to-force-after-effects-to-interpret-footage-at-a-specific-framerate